# Django migrations problem: Field id expectet a number but got 'China'

Tags: python, django

I set a default value of Country field in Item model as 'China'. Then i tried migrate and i showed an error that should set a default value in each of field. I've done it but after next migrate command i got an error "Field id expecter a number but got 'China'", but i change a default value to '4'.

**P.S.**: I don't use Model.objects.filter() anywhere. I just work with models only.

It's my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from slugger import AutoSlugField

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default='0')
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=CASCADE, default='White')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=CASCADE, default='SOMECATEGORY')
    age = models.ForeignKey('Age', on_delete=CASCADE, default='0')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default='')
    in_stock = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country', on_delete=CASCADE, default='4') # here was default value China
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

class Age(models.Model):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ages'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.age
```

Comment: you are getting this error because there is data that already exist and when your items models is migrating it looks for the default value in the connected model, i.e Country. I would recommend setting default to null and customizing your post save to add your "China" field by using Country.objects.get() method

Comment: i can't, when i do any changes and write python manage.py migrate it shows the same error

Comment: and i don't have any category, item, etc instances

Comment: it is probably because it keeps trying to run the migration that was generated when you set default as "China". Just go through your migrations.py files to see which file has your `default="China"` and delete that file and files that follow below it, then run the `python manage.py makemigrations` again and migrate (While making sure that your default is 0 or 4 as you mentioned in the comment)

Comment: finally, yes, i've found a migration with that default value and changed it, thanks!

Comment: I'll just add it in the answer below, mark it as correct so if anyone has a similar issue, they can find the solution as well.

Comment: yes, of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because it keeps trying to run the migration that was generated when you set default as `"China"`. Just go through your migrations.py files to see which file has your `default="China"` and delete that file and files that follow below it, then run the `python manage.py makemigrations` again and `migrate` (While making sure that your default is 0 or 4 as you mentioned in the comment)